# Easiest Way to Print Non-Strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm constantly doing this

```
puts “The temperature is “ + String(temperature) + “.”
```

in my debugging code, and another option is to use interpolation

```
puts “The temperature is #{temperature}.”
```

is there any less cumbersome way to do this?

**Edit:** This is just for debugging, if that matters.

Comment: What's cumbersome about interpolation? What more elegant way can you think of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None that are all that worthwhile for small cases like that.

Though, you should prefer interpolation as it's less expensive than concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to insert dynamic variables into strings is

```
#interpolation
"foo #{my_var} bar"
```

It will call the `to_s` method on whatever object the expression returns and insert that string.  It really the same as

```
#concatenation
"foo " + my_var.to_s + " bar"
```

But, as wfarr metioned, its faster to do interpolation.  Easier to read too.

Comment: It appears you got it backwards. Interpolation is the first example. Concatenation is the second example you gave.

Comment: Perhaps it got misinterpreted that way.  I clarified with labels :)

Comment: I had forgotten baout the .to_s method. Not a bad option... depends on your typing habits. I am not using this stuff in real code, but just to figure out what's happening.

Comment: to_s is generally THE way to turn an object into a string.  It's defined on the Object class that all ruby objects inherit from so its always available.  If you write your own classes its encouraged to override it with a decent implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach is to use assertions in automated tests.

For example using Test::Unit :-

```
assert_equal 25, temperature
```

I find that using automated tests dramatically cuts down on the amount of debugging code I have to write.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll check into this possibility. Answers like this make my stupid questions worth it.

Comment: So how can I get this code running from a Ruby program? TestCase.assert_not_nil(blah) I know I need some requires or something.

Comment: require 'test/unit'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_should_be_hot_today
    ...
    assert_equal 25, temperature
  end

end

Comment: Alternatively if you just want the assertions:
require 'test/unit/assertions'
include Test::Unit::Assertions
...
assert_equal 25, temperature

Comment: See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit/Assertions.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments, great that it's here :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Kernel#p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M006002)

```
p temperature #=> 10.25
```

When I'm debugging, I often label such statements just by copying the line, and using inserting a colon, making the variable into a symbol.

```
p :attributes #=> :attributes
p attributes  #=> { :mood => "happy", 5 => [] }
```

Or

```
p [:location, location] #=> [ :location, "@ work" ]
```

Note that Kernel#p calls #inspect on its arguments, instead of #to_s, but this normally provides more useful debugging info anyway.

Comment: Wow. Nice stuff. I'll check it out. Anything that can save typing in my eventually-deleted-statements helps.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to use irbtools gem which includes awesome_print or just awesome_print. 
I personally find it faster and less cumbersome to use in dev, then using interpolated strings, thou sometimes that's the only way to go.

You can do  this  on any object and it will give you a nicely formatted otput be that array, string or hash or even any other complex object that you may have - like  3-dimentional array printted as a tree structure. In order to have it awailable in your rails env - just  include it in the Gemfile in the development group, or add it to .irbrc - to always have it in your irb console. Then just do

```
require "awesome_print"
ap  MyGreatObject
```

here is a sample output from one of my projects

```
ap Address
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base {
                  :id => :integer,
      :address_line_1 => :string,
      :address_line_2 => :string,
      :address_line_3 => :string,
                :city => :string,
               :state => :string,
                 :zip => :string,
             :country => :string,
                :attn => :string,
         :category_id => :integer,
      :addressable_id => :integer,
    :addressable_type => :string,
          :created_at => :datetime,
          :updated_at => :datetime
}


 ap Address.first
  Address Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `addresses`.* FROM `addresses` LIMIT 1
#<Address:0x7bc5a00> {
                  :id => 1,
      :address_line_1 => "1 Sample Drive",
      :address_line_2 => nil,
      :address_line_3 => nil,
                :city => "Chicago",
               :state => "IL",
                 :zip => "60625",
             :country => "USA",
                :attn => nil,
         :category_id => 1,
      :addressable_id => 1,
    :addressable_type => "Warehouse",
          :created_at => Tue, 10 Jan 2012 14:42:20 CST -06:00,
          :updated_at => Tue, 17 Jan 2012 15:03:20 CST -06:00
}
```

Comment: No problem - it is a great gem. irbtools are good to. Also check out pry - it's a cool alternative to irb.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention - I use windows ( can't use my Macbook at work for multiple reasons), most of the time, Console2 helps to spruce up command prompt.

Comment: Yeah, my issue with gems is that you learn to like them and then they're not maintained. Once upon a time I thought http://rush.heroku.com/ was cool, until I realized that nobody is at the wheel. But I will check it all out, yes.

Comment: all off the mentoned gems have large user bases/ community /dedicated authors. I tend to stray away from gems that are not popular - as we don't have the manpower to maintain/update gems that nobody uses anymore. I tried to submit patches where I can - but except for DrNic nobody can maintain 100 open-source projects :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's always the possibility to use `printf` style formatting:

```
"The temperature is %s" % temperature
```

This would allow for finer formatting of numbers, etc. as well. But honestly, how much less "cumbersome" than using `#{}` interpolation can you expect to get?

Comment: To be honest, I type on a Spanish keyboard but I switch to English format half the time, so finding the number key and brackets is just not as easy as "thinger" + thinger like in Java. But yeah, the interpolation syntax is workable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do something stupid like this:

`"The temperature is %s." % temperature.to_s`

Personally I'd use interpolation